# htaccess global rewriting for subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
/api1
    /v1
/api2
    /v1
    /v2
```

Would it be possible to have an `.htaccess` file in the root (`/`) which rewrites all requests from `/api1/v1/*` to `/api1/v1/index.php` (same for every api/version combination) to handle them?

It should behave in such a way that:

- `/api1/v1/users -> /api1/v1/index.php`,
- `/api1/v1/users/action/paramater -> /api1/v1/index.php`
- `/api2/v1/projects/popular -> /api2/v1/index.php`
- `/api2/v2/projects/most_popular -> /api2/v2/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(api[0-9]+/v[0-9]+)/(?!index\.php).*$ $1/index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Looks great! Only problem is that the first subdirectory (`api$`) in my example is always like that, so the first part should be changed... What could I best use instead of the `api[0-9]` if I want to accept alphanumeric characters?

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9_]` should do the trick, right? As in: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+/v[0-9]+)/(?!index\.php).*$ $1/index.php [L,NC]`

Comment: Yes definitely `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+/v[0-9]+)/(?!index\.php).*$ $1/index.php [L,NC]` will work fine.